# Having Issues with cache_classes / Spork after changing to Capybara-Webkit from Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, webkit, spork

For a while I was using Selenium / Spork / Rspec, with cache_classes on false, and everything seemed to be working.

In switching over to webkit, I've started to get errors related to cache_classes (e.g. Expected User, got User), so I've been fighting with it to try to get cache_classes set to true.

However no matter what I do, I end up with the following error:

```
 Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:
   Unable to load URL: http://127.0.0.1:56398/login
```

I have tried all kinds of things... including:

- ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear in both the prefork and each _run blocks
- The code here: http://my.rails-royce.org/2012/01/14/reloading-models-in-rails-3-1-when-usign-spork-and-cache_classes-true/

Starting to wonder if I should just live with cache_classes = false, and figure out how to avoid the Factory girl errors.  Any help would be appreciated.  My spork file is as follows:

```
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rails'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require 'factory_girl'
  require 'authlogic/test_case'
  require 'email_spec'
  include Authlogic::TestCase

  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # == Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    ApplicationController.skip_before_filter :activate_authlogic

    config.include(EmailSpec::Helpers)
    config.include(EmailSpec::Matchers)
    config.include Capybara::DSL

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    #config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[ages coefficients weights1 weights2 weights3 weights4 weights5 weights6 weights7 weights8 etfs]}
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
      Capybara.current_driver = :webkit if example.metadata[:js]
      #Capybara.current_driver = :selenium if example.metadata[:js]
      activate_authlogic
      ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
      Capybara.use_default_driver if example.metadata[:js]
    end

    Capybara.default_selector = :css

  end

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  ## SUPPORT METHODS ##
  ## (erased for clarity) ##


  ## ##
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
end

Spork.each_run do
  #FactoryGirl.reload

  # Required to fix a recurring error when testing Active_Admin stuff
  # See here: http://railsgotchas.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/activeadmin-spork-and-the-infamous-undefined-local-variable-or-method-view_factory/
  # Delete at some point if active admin or whoever fixes this
  ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :arb, lambda { |template|
    "self.class.send :include, Arbre::Builder; @_helpers = self; self.extend ActiveAdmin::ViewHelpers; @__current_dom_element__ = Arbre::Context.new(assigns, self); begin; #{template.source}; end; current_dom_context"
  }

  #ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
end
```

**UPDATE :**  Adding an example spec just in case it helps....

```
describe "Items" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    activate_authlogic
    b = # something not important
  end

  describe "usage paths" do

    it "the form directly from the basic_simulation show page should have correctly functioning javascript validation", :js => true do
      request_sign_in(@user) # This is a helper method which goes through the login form
      visit '/basic_simulation'
      fill_in "amount", :with => "-5000"
      click_button "Calculate"
      page.should have_selector("label.jquery-validator.amount-error", :text => "Please enter a value greater than or")
      fill_in "amount", :with => "5000"
      click_button "Calculate"
      page.should have_selector("input#amount", :value => "5000")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are having issues due to threading problems with Capybara-webkit and the test suite.

Jose Valim explains it much more clearly in [a recent blog post.](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/)

If you follow his recommendations then you should be able to turn on transactional fixtures, remove database cleaner altogether and no longer have issues with your data during tests while using capybara-webkit. You'll get a nice boost in testing performance as well.

The trick though is to make sure that Jose's suggestion is in the `Spork.each_run` block or it will not work. For clarity here are the relevant parts of my `spec_helper.rb`.

```
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'capybara/rspec'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|

    config.mock_with :rspec

    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    Capybara.default_driver     = :rack_test
    Capybara.default_selector   = :css
    Capybara.javascript_driver  = :webkit
  end
end

Spork.each_run do

  if Spork.using_spork?
    ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers
  end

  require 'factory_girl_rails'

  # Forces all threads to share the same connection, works on Capybara because it starts the web server in a thread.
  class ActiveRecord::Base
    mattr_accessor :shared_connection
    @@shared_connection = nil

    def self.connection
      @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
    end
  end

  ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
end
```

A few other small suggestions:

- If you are using the latest version of factory_girl_rails then you
  should be using `require factory_girl_rails` in the `Spork.each_run`
  block and `require factory_girl` should be removed from the `prefork`
- The latest factory_girl_rails also no longer requires `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear` at all, although some people are still having issues without it so you should test removing it.
- I'm still not sure about the need for `ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers` but in any case you would only need it if you are using observers and I understand that it should be in the `each_run` block.

Try all that and see if it works for you.

Comment: You mentioned that this allows me to turn transactional_fixtures back on - from very quick googling around it would seem my issues are with cache_classes ... Will the approach above allow me to set both (use_transactional_fixtures & cache_classes) to true?

Comment: And when using  "Capybara.javascript_driver  = :webkit", how do you indicate in your tests to run javascript?  (I'm currently doing the :js => true business with Capybara.current_driver = xx if metadata...)

Comment: Yes. You can change `config.cache_classes = true` in the `test.rb` file. Indicating js files is the same as before - this is a Capabara indicator which will then pass to the selected js driver which is set in the `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: I gave it a shot, however javascript is still an issue... I get the following eror:  Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:
       Unable to load URL: http://127.0.0.1:49331/login     I get the exact same error for every javascript spec I have, as I have the driver go through the login page to log in.

Comment: Do you know what could be causing this?  I have a pretty much identical spec_helper.rb file... I will post an example spec in the original question

Comment: If I do a "save_and_open_page" I see the following error in the browser: "The connection was reset"

Comment: Hmmm. I haven't seen this error before, but there is an issue that looks similar at the repo see https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/109 there is a comment about 5 down which talks about redirects which may be of help.

Comment: Although I'm not going to mark this answer as accepted (I'm still having issues) a big rate up for you for being so helpful!!

Comment: Good luck with getting it all working, glad that I could help get a few steps closer.

Comment: Turns out that the "Unable to load URL" error comes up any time you get an exception using Capybara/webkit.... I had an issue with my application that caused errors only in the test environment.  With your stuff in place, it all seems to be working (with transactional fixtures), and FAST!

Comment: Correction - transactional fixtures are working, but cache_classes still does not